# How to get all data matched each record from mongodb using mongoose and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Tried to get value of product_name from my mongodb using mongoose but i do not know how to do it.

My DB Data collection:

```
{
_id:ObjectId("5ecea02ebb6f3c19e86fe805"),
product_name:"Test1"
},
{
_id:ObjectId("5ecea02ebb6f3c19e86fe806"),
product_name:"Test2"
},
{
_id:ObjectId("5ecea02ebb6f3c19e86fe807"),
product_name:"Test3"
},
{
_id:ObjectId("5ecea02ebb6f3c19e86fe808"),
product_name:"Test4"
},
{
_id:ObjectId("5ecea02ebb6f3c19e86fe809"),
product_name:"Test5"
}
```

data.controller.js:

```
module.exports.getData = (req, res, next) => { 
var tableCate = mongoose.model("Product"); 
    tableCate.find({ product_name }, function(err, docs) {
    if (err) {
        console.log( err);
        return
    } else {
        console.log(docs)// output should be Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4,Test5
     }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

db.collection.find returns a Cursor which is A pointer to the result set of a query, to access the result you can use `db.collection.find({}).toArray()` to return an array of documents or

```
.forEach(function(item){
// and you can print or do what you want with each item
})
```

Comment: How to get matched record..exmaple i want to check product_name ="test6" there or not?

Comment: You can use .forEach and inside you can check what you want by `if(item.product_name=='test6'){console.log(item)}`